# Apache ftpserver uploadnotify

Tags: java, apache, ftp

I'm using Apache ftpserver (Java). I need to have a nofication in my program when a file is uploaded through the ftp. 
It seems to be possible but i can't find the way how to do it.

Any solutions out there?

mina.apache.org/ftpserver

Answer (score 3):

You can get all notifications using ftplet. 
Check this out ... 
http://apilevel.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/ftplet-servlet-for-apache-ftpserver/

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that, you have a desktop program, which is running on the ftpserver itself.. So as soon as any file is uploaded to the same ftpserver, your program must inform it...Right.!!

Lets see....

1. I am sure you have created a directory in the ftp server where the files will be uploaded.
2. Make this program of your which is running on the same server to **keep looking at the total nos of files in that folder/directory say for every 2mins or as per your requirement..Once the program notices that the nos of files have increased then i will raise an event of some kind in the program to inform u.**

How to do it...

1. Create a **Separate thread** to keep looping the directory for any change in the nos of 
   files. **Do Not** make the Event Dispatcher thread to do it..**else your GUI will be Hanged.**
2. Try the logic below..

   ```
   private static int max = 0;    // i am assuming the folder is Empty.

    while(true) {

    File f = new File("path_of_files_on_ftp_server");
    File[] farr = f.listFiles();

    if ( farr.length > max ){

              // There has been an upload......
              // Raise the alarm here, by doing some event....
              max = farr.length ;


        }

    else {

          continue;
        }
   ```

   }

Comment: I use a project from apache, see link
http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/

It would be better if I could use a callback in the project.

Best Regards
Mikael

Comment: Dear i have given you a clear layout of what is to be done.... just create a separate commandline or gui based program on the basis of the above description i gave you, its not about me solving this out, its about you to reach your goal by walking on the way i showed u..

Comment: It's works but I want to solve it with solutions inside apache ftpserver.

Best Regards
Mikael

Comment: The code is inside the Apache server.... The code is running on the same machine as that of the FTPSERVER. Now if you want to run the software separately, then you will need 2 different code, doing a Client-Server socket

Comment: My program is integrated with a apache ftpserver. So I'm able to make some nice gui on it. A industrial camera will send not okey pictures to this server. Then I need to have a notify very quickly for making some action with the picture. I will then also show the picture in my window.